# Bootstrap 4 - 2 columns same height one with scroll

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'be been searching all over for a solution to this issue. Im trying to create a page with a video player on the left, and a chat on the right. For the video player, I'm using the `embed-responsive`class so the video player resizes according to the view. The problem I am having is with the chat box on the right. I can't get the overflow to scroll. It just expands and pushes the right div down and its no longer the height of the left div

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <div  class="container-fluid p-0 mb-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 p-0">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <video controls>
            <source src="#" type="video/mp4" />
            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
          </video>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 p-0">
        <div class="bg-dark text-white h-100" style="overflow: scroll">
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
          <p>test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution to your problem consist of adding class `overflow-auto` to the `col-4` wrapping the chat and use `JQuery` to set the height of this wrapper to be equal to the height of the video when document is load. Also you will have to setup a listener on `$(window).resize()` to calculate the `height` again when the window's size change.

## Working Example:

Note I have changed classes to `col-8` and `col-4` so you can see it whitout going to full screen.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#chatWrapper").height($("#myVideo").height());
    
    $(window).resize(function()
    {
        $("#chatWrapper").height($("#myVideo").height());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-8">
    <div id="myVideo" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <video controls>
        <source src="#" type="video/mp4"/>
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="chatWrapper" class="col-4 overflow-auto">
    <div class="bg-dark text-white">
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want the columns to be the full height of the viewport. I want the left column with the video to be "in charge". Whatever the height of that is, that is the height of the right column and anything else scrolls.

Comment: @ChrisKooken Ok, I have updated, however in this case you will need to use `Jquery` (and not the slim version).